# How to fix "Reaction role code does not work" discord

Tags: javascript, discord

So I am trying to make a code that when you react a specific reaction on a specific message it gives a role

I tried a lot of codes on internet but nothing worked

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", function(users) {
    message.guild.members.get("589752122954874922")
});
```

No Error messages.

Comment: as long as there is only one not upvoted answer, you should be able to delete your post. But please don't vandalize it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using discord.js

If so you are in luck becouse they have a guide on reactions here: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#awaiting-reactions

And for the role, here is the documentation of the GuildMember class's addRole function: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole

Comment: sorry not so useful because I need a code I don't understand much in js

Comment: Well it is hard to write code in a language you don't understand, don't you want to learn javascript first?

Comment: I learnt js good but not so good and I can't use discord.js too